# Git push failed, looking for partial file history deletion

Tags: git, heroku, binary, push, history

I've been updating a facebook app through the basic workflow using heroku & git. I'm the only one working on it and the only thing that happens is a new binary once a week.
git commit -am "new update"
git push heroku

The binary has grown to about 30 MB. And lately all the push commands fail like this:
Counting objects: 7, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
fatal: sha1 file '' write error: Invalid argument
error: failed to push some refs to 'mysecretgitplace'

I've looked in a lot of places and found out this is a very common issue that seems to be caused by nothing in particular and could be anything.
Now as the only thing that changed over time is the size of the binary increasing and the number of commits increasing it's probably just that.

So now I'd like to try decreasing the server space I'm using by removing/destroying/obliterating the history of this one binary file (completely except for the current version (on the server at head/master whatever). I'd do this every once in a while in addition to weekly submitting the binary.

Is there a command that lets me do that? (without re-adding the whole "deleted" history of the file once I submit a new binary)

(It's probably obvious I just want to work on my game and not bother with all the server, version control stuff.)

Answer (score 1):

Git allow you to remove part of your history by [filtering](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) it.

In your case, the first example should do the trick: `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' HEAD`.

Nevertheless, you should read very carefully about this command and what needs to be done on your repository and your remote for this to be effective (notably, you have to use `git gc` in your local repository).

You can read more on this in the [github help section](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data).

As a side note, git is not really good with managing big files (look into `git annex` for a potential solution).

Comment: Yeah, I stumbled upon the filter command but it scares me a little and I was kind of hoping for a simpler solution. (I've run gc regularly, but local repository is a minimum of 500MB, used to be > 1 GB though)  If I have to I'll simply rename the binary, completely delete the old one and fix the html/php to point at the new name, but come on.. you know. I'll check out the annex command thanks!

Comment: Renaming won't help. You HAVE TO wipe out this file from your history if you want to get memory space back. Every version of your file is stored in your .git/ folder anyway. That's why it's so big.

Comment: So this was not a great solution.

Some things I encountered:
"fatal: ambiguous argument 'rm': unknown revision or path not in the working tree"
I didn't find anything wrong with it until I realised I'm working on a european machine with united states 101 keyboard and language settings. So this:
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' HEAD
should be this:
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename" HEAD

Comment: I had been focusing on why there is a difference between the commands given in the first two examples:
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm filename' HEAD
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' HEAD
Needless to say, it wasted a lot of time.


So after that really easy fix it turns out the current version of the file was deleted as well. I guess I didn't express that clearly enough, but it was paramount the current version be left intact.

Comment: Also it seems Heroku was having issues with pushes failing. My average speed over here is 10KB/s so that further adds to the frustration.

And on top of this, it did not fix my problem. If I try to push the binary it still bails out with the same error.
Now however, there is no current app online and working.

Great.

Comment: Your question was to remove a huge file from your history, and I answered it. `git rm --cached` removed only the files in your history. You still have it in your repository as an untracked file. So you could have added it again. What I would do in your case is 1) clean up the repository and add this large file to your gitignore and 2) push the file using another mean, or store it elsewhere (aws is a good candidate). Keeping large files in git folders is unmanageable in the long run anyway.

Comment: Hm. If --cached only removed the files in history and not the current version, why then is my app gone? If it became "untracked" how can I restore it? And just that single current version I mean..

Comment: First of all, you probably used `git push --force` already. If not, it is not possible for your file to have just disappeared from your server. You should be able to do `git add your_file` and `git commit` as normal to have the current version of your file. If you have not ran `git gc --prune` or something alike, your file, and every commit that referenced it, should still be somewhere in you .git/ folder. Anyway, read https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data. Everything is very well explained.

Comment: Yeah I've already used force, and also locally I have the newer binary that I was unable to push in the first place. The article you mentioned also uses git gc with the agressive option, which is supposedly something that shouldn't really be used. All in all, these options are way to much trouble for a simple 30 mb file and it takes up way too much of my time and I also dislike server/file management stuff. So I'll solve it another way. Thanks for trying.